# Round-robin writing events in chat

Tags: discussion, chat

In an effort to get some people into the Writers.SE chat and to have a little fun, I'd like to propose starting a weekly round-robin writing event.

These go something like this:

- First person comes up with the opening to a story
- After a set amount of writing is complete (e.g. a paragraph, a certain number of sentences) or a certain amount of time has elapsed, another person *continues* that same story.
- The story is passed around the group one or more times. The final time around, the last person comes up with a conclusion. You can then mix up the order and start a new story.
- Goofiness is encouraged.

If anyone is interested, please answer this question with the days and times that you'd be available. Include your time zone - StackExchange users come from all over the world.

Hopefully we can find enough people with overlapping times to try this with one or more groups.

Comment: very cool -- I added the featured tag so this will be shown on the sidebar on the main site

Comment: I'm afraid I left this hanging. Unfortunately, I'm not really active on Writers.SE anymore. If people still want to do this, someone else will have to organize it.

Comment: thanks for the update; if anyone else is participating just leave notes in chat or comments on your posts here to let others know of your availability.

Answer (score 4):

I'm available

- **Monday - Friday:** 8-11PM CST (01:00 - 4:00 UTC)
- **Sunday:** 2-10PM CST (19:00 - 03:00 UTC)

Answer (score 4):

Monday - Friday: 8-11PM EST 
Saturday: Flexible, much of the day
Sunday: 9-2, 6-11PM EST

Answer (score 2):

I'm an overworked college student until May 10 (and become one again in August), so while I can promise to write *something* I'm not going to attest to quality. DX It's amazing what seems like good English after you've been doing math for a few hours straight...

Anyway, I'm available (for now):

Monday, Wednesday, Friday: 2:00-10:00 PM EDT (1800-0200 UTC)

Tuesday, Thursday, Saturday, Sunday: 3:00-10:00 PM EDT (1900-0200 UTC)

After May 10: I can do anything. Who needs a regular sleep schedule? Not college students! Everyone knows that!

Starting August 17, Monday, Wednesday, Friday will change to something like 6:00-10:00 PM EDT (2200-0200 UTC)...and starting in January 2012 it would be something else...and for several more Januaries and Augusts thereafter.

If that's too irregular/ complicated to make this work, let me know and I'll delete this answer. This sounds like fun, though!

Answer (score 2):

weekdays on and off from 9am-4pm EDT.

- Are seriously bad puns allowed?
- Are we allowed to stop mid-sentence?
- Are we allowed to bring in random TV
  and/or movie characters?
- How about breaking the fourth wall?

Comment: It says goofiness is encouraged....and you can do a lot of goofy things to a sentence that stops midway.

Comment: I would be fine with all of those except perhaps the 3rd, since other participants may not know anything about a given TV or movie character.

Comment: How about limiting it to extremely well-known characters like Captain Kirk? The number of people in the world who haven't heard of Star Trek is approximately equal to the number of people in the world who haven't heard of ketchup.

Comment: @Lauren Actually, those people do exist. I still need to force one of my friends to watch an episode of Star Trek, so she can understand my Kirk jokes...Still, Someone that iconic would be quick to wiki...

Comment: But she's *heard* of Star Trek. Even if she hasn't watched it, she knows the show exists. (The ketchup line is a joke I snagged from one of Shatner's books, IIRC.)

Comment: She'd heard of "Star Trek," yes, but neither Captain Kirk nor William Shatner....Also, since goofiness is encouraged, I think introducing pop-culture characters would be fine....as long as I can immediately kill them off, Strongbad style, if I haven't heard of them. ;)...Okay, well maybe not Strongbad style, but you get the idea...

Comment: Oh, by all means. Just be prepared for the character to find some hilariously improbable but internally logical way to resurrect. :)

Answer (score 2):

Normally available Mon-Fri from 19h00 - 22h00 (GMT), and most weekends at random times. I'm a little snowed under at the moment, so cannot commit to regular appearances, but will do my best.

Oh, and one additional point: I also need to try and sort out my chat login, never works for some reason.

Comment: for issues like that post on [Meta.SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) or e-mail team@stackexchange.com.

Comment: @justkt - Thanks for the heads up, will do if I need to. Going to try logging out and logging back in to see if that resolves the issue first.